# Powershell: ForEach + GetMsol loop

Tags: powershell, loops, foreach

I had tried to take a look on videos, went thru articles in my 2 books but still cannot nail it :-/ Goal of my script: to **get the UPN's** based on **DisplayName of user's accounts**.

My CSV example:

- DisplayName
- user1
- user2
- user3

I am successfull when I just run:

```
Get-MsolUser -SearchString 'user1' | Select-Object UserPrincipalName
```

Importing all displaynames to array:

```
$userlist = Import-Csv .\ul.csv
```

Check I did import correctly:

```
$userlist
```

***Sadly I'm failing here: to run the loop thru the imported CSV "objects" :-/***

I tried 1:

```
$userlist.foreach(
            {
                Get-MsolUser -SearchString 'DisplayName' | Select-Object UserPrincipalName
            })
```

I tried 2:

```
foreach ($user in $userlist)
{
    Get-MsolUser -Searchstring DiplayName | Select-Object UserPrincipalName 
}
```

I tried 3:

```
$userlist | ForEach-Object {Get-MsolUser -Searchstring DisplayName | Select-Object UserPrincipalName}
```

None of them worked :-(

Comment: Given that it's a CSV file with a header row, the appropriate expression would be `-SearchString $_.DisplayName` or `-SearchString $user.DisplayName`

Comment: Mathias, thanks for your hint. I tried to edit mine first, so it is: `$userlist.foreach(
                {
                    Get-MsolUser -SearchString $_DisplayName | Select-Object UserPrincipalName
                })
}` It replied with error: Max results..... so I added parameter - ALL. But now it listed all the UPNs :-/ not only the 3, saved in array from Import CSV. What I am still missing, please?

Comment: _What I am still missing_ You missed the dot between `$_` and `DisplayName`

Comment: Yeah, the dot is import: `$_.DisplayName`

Comment: Thanks gents, but even when added the dot, as you mentioned, script is still listing all the UPNs not only those 3, from my CSV :-/

Comment: Found the issue on my side, it was a space in my CSV. I had Display Name instead of correct DisplayName in mine CSV header.